# Align google ad code on my blog

Tags: html, css, adsense

I have this google adsense code I want next to logo but how do I make it so it goes to the right more?

```
<div class="pad group">     
                <?php echo wpb_site_name(); ?>
                        <div >
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7548335119849446";
/* Techs Leaderboard */
google_ad_slot = "9543222930";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>       </div>
            </div>
```

The website is http://techsdiary.com/ if you see it is not aligning with a gap from logo

Thank you

Comment: To `#logo`, add `margin-right: 25px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the HTML to this:

```
<ins style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;float: right;">
```

Adding in `float:right`.. alternatively, you could also just add this to the stylesheet:

```
ins {
    float: right;
}
```

As a side note, why is there an iframe within an iframe within an iframe..?

Result:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the iframe? I was just adding the code google adsense gives you. I am not a developer so I had bit trouble implementing into my wordpress themes header.

Comment: @ToddFoster This is what I meant about the iframes http://i.stack.imgur.com/KD9cd.png

Comment: I have no idea, this is a theme from theme forest and all I have done is added google adsense, alexa and analytic code to it.

Comment: Alright, pretty sure it's just dynamically generated by Google then. Glad it worked, let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: I guess it's the ad doing it that is generated? I am not sure, must be something to do with google.

Comment: I wish I was able to contact your privately for contact information but it does not seem this site allows that. :(